# Lebesgue measure of the union $\bigcup A_n$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Any idea how to calculate the Lebesgue measure of the union $\bigcup A_n$,  $$A_n:\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}<x^2+y^2<\frac{1}{2^n}\right\}$$

Is there an example of an unbounded set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is Lebesgue-measurable and $\mu(A)=2$?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use that the two dimensional Lebesgue measure of a circle is zero to show that the Lebesgue measure of $\bigcup A_n$ equals to the area of the *unit disk* (supposed that $n$ starts with $0$).
2. Yes, in $\Bbb R^2$ consider e.g. the area below the graph of $f(x)=1/x^2$ for $x>1$. This is unbounded but has finite area. This can be rotated and scaled to get an unbounded $A$ in $\Bbb R^3$ with volume $2$.

Comment: how can i prove that the two dimensional Lebesgue measure of a circle is zero???

Comment: Suppose the unit circle has measure $u$. Then the measure of a circle of radius $r$ is $r^2\cdot u$, so the (closed) unit disk would have measure $+\infty$ because it is $>u\cdot(1+\displaystyle\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2+\displaystyle\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)^2)+\dots=\infty$.

Comment: There are some things that i don't understand. Suppose that we want to approximate(using the definition of outer and inner measure) the lebesgue measure of a circle of radius r and the lebesgue measure of the disk of radius r in R^2. That means that we have to find compact subsets to approximate it fromthe inside and open subsets to approximate it from the outside. when i'm trying to do that,using rectangles, i'm getting as a result tha both circle and disk have zero measure! But it doesn't seem right to me! what is the right way??